# CSS Dashboard with tab-content causes main area to display below navigation

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Got an ASP MVC 4/5 project, using VS2012. Added is bootstrap 3.2

I had a look at the few others who had problems with Twitter Bootstrap's Dashboard example, but they did not enable me to formulate a solution to my own problem.

I have a dashboard, and to show the different pages I made use of the tab-content and tab-panes css classes. However the main area ends up below and to the right of the navigation. The other similar questions mentioned row-fluid, which the latest bootstrap doesn't have. I also tried the various answers suggested in them by modifying my css.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients" data-toggle="tab">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#orders" data-toggle="tab">Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#stock" data-toggle="tab">Stock</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main tab-content">
            <h1 class="page-header" style="margin-top: 0 !important;">Dashboard</h1>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="clients">
                @Html.Action( "Index", "Client")
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="orders">
                @Html.Action("Index", "Order")
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="stock">
                @Html.Action("Index", "Stock")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps my css is wrong, or perhaps my implementation of getting the pages to load in the main area is wrong. Thank you to any answers/suggestions to get this to work.

Other things I tried: To use ajax actionlink with the div as the target update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using `col-*` values you don't need to use `offset` classnames:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main tab-content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this **[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/IJVIRnJ0Af)**

Comment: Thanks! The removal of both offsets(I tried removing one offset at a time earlier) worked, the main area is now where it should be. Any idea why the nav is not all along the side from top to bottom? The nav is also getting pushed down a bit now? Let me know if I must upload a screenshot.

Comment: If you can will be better to understand @anon_4324654

Comment: Thanks for eagerness to help! I figured it out though, in the stock controller for the stock tab I had simply created the method but not changed the code, which was returning a View rather than a partial. It now works well and looks as intended after working on the code more.